# Querying from a schema with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scheme with three tables with the following structure

```
donuts (name: string, price: integer) 
grocery (no: string, gname: string, minCredit: integer) 
distributor (dname: string, gno: string, deliverydate: date)
```

distributor.dname and distributor.gno are foreign keys that reference donuts and grocery which keys are name and no respectivey I am having trouble with 2 queries I am trying to write:

1. query for the number of grocery (grocery, no: string) with the highest minCredit requirement among the donuts in grocery named "Jelly"

   ```
        SELECT g.no 
        FROM grocery g, distributor dd, donut d
        WHERE minCredit >= * AND d.name = "JELLY"
   ```

This doesnt work

2. A query to find the grocery number (grocery, no: string) shared by every donut with the price above 2

   I tried

   ```
   SELECT g.no
   FROM grocery g, distributor dd, donut d
   WHERE g.price >= 2
   ```

This doesn't do the right thing either. Any help is appreciated

Comment: learn how to join tables to start with

Comment: Can you tell us explicitly what is happening when you say the query "doesn't work"?

Comment: In terms of syntax it is correct but its not selecting the correct data. I am a little new to sql and not sure if I wrote the query correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1.

```
SELECT g.no
FROM grocery g, distributor dd, donut d
WHERE g.no = dd.gno
  AND d.name = dd.dname
  AND d.name = 'JELLY'
ORDER BY g.minCredit DESC LIMIT 1
```

2.

```
SELECT g.no
FROM grocery g, distributor dd, donut d
WHERE g.no = dd.gno
  AND d.name = dd.dname
  AND d.price >= 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain what the purpose of DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: This limits the result set to 1 and orders them by minCredit descending. Effectively you get the maximum value of minCredit. Without putting much thought into it, it was the "quick and dirty" way I came up with.